# How to maintain order of key-value in DataFrame same as JSON?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Sample JSON data:

```
{"name": "dev","salary": 100,"occupation": "engg","address": "noida"}
{"name": "karthik","salary": 200,"occupation": "engg","address": "blore"}
```

Spark Java code:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(jsonPath);
df.printSchema();
df.show(false);
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- occupation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: long (nullable = true)


+-------+-------+----------+------+
|address|name   |occupation|salary|
+-------+-------+----------+------+
|noida  |dev    |engg      |10000 |
|blore  |karthik|engg      |20000 |
+-------+-------+----------+------+
```

Columns are arranged in the alphabetical order. **Is there any way to maintain natural order?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide `schema` while reading the `json` and it will maintain the order.

```
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] { 
    DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true),
    DataTypes.createStructField("salary", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
    DataTypes.createStructField("occupation", DataTypes.StringType, true),
    DataTypes.createStructField("address", DataTypes.StringType, true)});

DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().schema(schema).json(jsonPath);
df.printSchema();
df.show(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have got two options

1. create a schema according to the order of your json data and apply
   while reading it and
2. Select fields from the table as the order you want.

Better option is to use schema while reading input.