# How to maintain order of key in DataFrame same as JSON file?

Tags: json, pyspark

when I make a df.schema() in pyspark of a JSON file, it returns the keys in alphabetical order, and I would like them to be in the same order as the JSON file. can someone help me ?

Lily

Comment: Just curious, in what the ordering of keys of json file is important?

Comment: I infer a schema from json to create a DDL table hive, and I want to have the schema in the same order as the json file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to maintain order of key-value in DataFrame same as JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587169/how-to-maintain-order-of-key-value-in-dataframe-same-as-json)

Comment: Not really. i have a  long json and i can't create a schema according to the order of my json manually